# Last song in Gale's aparment

Tags: breaking-bad, soundtrack

When Jesse approaches Gale Boetticher's apartment in *Breaking Bad*, a slow, melodious song plays. Does anybody know what it's called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you mean this song here, "[Man Chang Fei](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7iafdBUpIO4)"?

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Couldn't stop myself listening for an hour, even though I don't get it completely